# How to colorize output of ls ?

Tags: linux, centos, colors, console

I'm running CentOS in Linux text mode. When I run the command `ls /usr/`, the output is too hard to read (dark blue on black). How can I change the text coloring?

[image: Screenshot of the ls output]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are wanting to change your colours in the console, that is **outside X**, then you can specify colours in your `.bashrc`, like so:

```
if [ "$TERM" = "linux" ]; then
    echo -en "\e]P0222222" #black
    echo -en "\e]P8222222" #darkgrey
    echo -en "\e]P1803232" #darkred
    ....
    fi
```

Where you are defining black as `#222222` See this post for the details: http://phraktured.net/linux-console-colors.html

If you are working **in X**, then you can customize your setup by defining your colours in your `.Xresources` like so:

```
!black
 *color0:  #3D3D3D
 *color8:  #5E5E5E
!red
 *color1:  #8C4665
 *color9:  #BF4D80
 ...
```

and then sourcing this file when you start X, typically from your `.xinitrc`:

`xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`

The Arch Wiki has a page on .Xresources that explains all of the options:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xresources

Another enhancement you can make **either in X or not** is to specify all of the different filetypes that you would like to colour—and their respective colours in a `.dir_colors` file, like so:

```
.xinitrc       01;31 
.Xauthority    01;31
.Xmodmap       00;31
.Xresources    01;33
 ...
```

To get started, copy `/etc/dir_colors` to your user's `/home` directory and make your changes. Then source this from your `.bashrc` with `eval $(dircolors -b ~/.dir_colors)` This will allow you fine-grained control over the colours of files and filetypes when you use `ls`.

You can find (an incredibly detailed and thorough) `.dir_colors` example file here:
https://github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS/blob/master/LS_COLORS

With a combination of all three approaches, you can create a reasonably uniform setup, whether you are working in the console or in X.

Comment: i am sorry, i am a new learner of linux. i installed it in linux text. there is no console. all the thing are running in command line. thank you,

Comment: Yes: that is what I meant when I said outside X - in the TTY consoles (TTY 1-7).

Comment: jasonwryan,i run the command vim /etc/DIR_COLORS 
the DIR is 01;34 HOW TO CHANGE TO teal color. thank you,

Comment: The term colours are here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html Green is `00;32` and light/bold green is `1;32` The only way to get teal is to use the method I described above to define one of those 16 colours as a hex equivalent of teal.

Comment: sorry if this is a beginners question, but does your answer change for a Unix system in OS X?

Comment: @CharlieParker I haven't tested in the console, but the approach for the terminal using `.Xresources` works fine...

Answer (score 9):

The file you want is `/etc/DIR_COLORS`. I had the exact same issue as you and changed directories to a teal color. Works much nicer.

```
cp /etc/DIR_COLORS /home/yourusername/.dir_colors
```

Edit `/home/yourusername/.dir_colors`, you will see this line:

```
DIR 01;34    #directory
```

Change that to this:

```
DIR 01;36    #directory
```

Which makes directory colors teal.

Comment: when i run the command /etc/DIR_COLORS  it output permission denied.  i am the root user, why? how to change the color to teal. thank you

Comment: @run It's not a command, it's a configuration file; open it in a text editor

Comment: the DIR is 01;34  HOW TO CHANGE TO teal color. thank you,

Comment: @MaxMackie This does not seem to work for me (copied to `~/.dir_colors`) and changed everything to `00`. Found that I have to open a new terminal. How is this enforced/attached to the current terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can set ls colors manually but I prefer this approach:

First of all there is the

```
dircolors
```

command.

```
dircolors --print-database > ~/.dir_colors
```

change the colors inside that file (it is quite self explanatory, and the colors are visualized inside the file)
apply the changes:

```
eval $(dircolors ~/.dir_colors)
```

for persistent use put this in `~./bashrc`:

```
if [ -f ${HOME}/.dir_colors ]; then
  eval $(dircolors ~/.dir_colors)
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ls --color=no` flag is the most direct option. A shorter version is `ls --col=n`.

Piping `ls` sets `--color=no` automatically. `ls | cat` or `ls | tee` will work.

Also possible, `ls | grep .`, which makes all output red by default, or `ls | grep ''` which makes all output white by default.