# Booting into shell instead of graphical interface

Tags: shell, startup, user-interface, lubuntu

I have a laptop with lubuntu. It's great but I wish LXDE was optional instead of autostarting.

So my question is, what can I do to make it boot directly into a text only mode, not loading anything extra until I do something like `start x` ? My goal is to have my system be as lightweight as possible until I need the extra stuff.

Comment: The init system in Debian Wheezy is [sysvinit](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/sysvinit), while Lubuntu as a Ubuntu variant uses [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/). Therefore answers applicable to Debian Wheezy might not be applicable to Lubuntu and vice versa.

Comment: While Wheezy currently leaves the choice of init to the user, the proposed solution with `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` works with Debian and all its derivates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable the login manager permanently on Ubuntu you can do the following:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'manual' > /etc/init/lightdm.override"
```

To start the login manager manually when needed you would do:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

To stop it manually:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Comment: @user11177 This question covers changing the ls directory colors: [How to colorize output of ls?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19219/how-to-colorize-output-of-ls)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit this file, `/etc/default/grub`, and change this line:

```
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

To this:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

#### References

- [Grub2 - Ubuntu community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)
- [How do I boot into true text mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92276/how-do-i-boot-into-true-text-mode)