# What file type categories do colors in the terminal represent in various distros (by default)?

Tags: files, ls

I'm discovering new file type categories (if one can call different colors in the terminal in such a manner) almost on a daily basis. Still, I haven't found an exhaustive list of all recognized file types (compressed, pipe, directory, music, etc.) and the respective colors on the terminal, and that's a resource I'd appreciate to have. Is there a complete list for any Unix-based system? I'd like a full table for many distros, options, etc.; but if you'd give me a few really useful informative links, perhaps someone can add it up into a table (maybe this should be a community-wiki question, however, I can't mark it as such).

Comment: See the output of `dircolors -p`. That has nothing to do with Unix, that's just default settings for the GNU implementation of `ls`.

Comment: @Stephane, I knew the colors had to be somewhere in my computer! But you mean all GNU-Linux distros give the same color by default? Also, in other Unix-based systems, is there any color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the colours for individual file types yourself, using `~/.dir_colors`. See this related question: [How to colourize the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19219/how-to-colorize-output-of-ls).

[trapd00r's .dir_colors file](https://github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS/blob/master/LS_COLORS) is a particularly detailed one and will give you a good idea of the range of file types available on Linux systems.

Comment: I had heard it could be done (although through the terminal's GUI). I'd also like to know about other Unix-based systems, what's their (if any) default `ls` output color? Also, I'd like to have all [those](https://github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS/blob/master/LS_COLORS) in an answer in a table together with the non-extended version (as @Stephane referred, provided by `dircolors`) and other normal versions (giving both the numbers representing the color and the same color as foreground).