# Is there a way to colourize the output of a command without using bashrc/bash_profile?

Tags: osx, pipe, colors

I have made a program where I can read several logs from different programs, I want to colourize certain terms in the output , so I can find the more interesting parts. (I will not use `grep` or anything similar because I still need to read the entire log, I just want to make certain interesting terms different colours to find them quickly).

[I found this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19221), but again, it's not what I'm looking for. I am looking for a way to pipe the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For colourizing the output of command or contents of a file, I can think of two easy methods that may work well:

- `grep` - it can be made to show the rest of the file as well, and do multiple matches with a few advanced options - for example:

  ```
  grep --color -iE 'log|kernel' -C 999
  grep --color -iE 'log|kernel|$'
  ```

  The first searches for `log` and `kernel` case-insensitively, and shows the surrounding 999 lines. The second searches for `log`, `kernel` and a character present in every line (as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366/convince-grep-to-output-all-lines-not-just-those-with-matches)) case-insensitively. For more info you may be able to consult `man grep` if it available, or read the manual for [GNU grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) or [OSX grep](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html).
- [`python-pygments`](http://pygments.org/) - should be available via [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/). Can be used for syntax highlighting, it may have a [lexer](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/) available for what you want to process.

Also, for generally formatting output, you may be able to use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#graphics) - e.g:

```
echo -e "\033[31mred\033[0m"
echo -e "\033[34mblue\033[0m"
```

The `\033` is a escape character, and after that you can specify codes to do different things - you can specify multiple ones as well:

```
echo -e "\033[1;31mbold red\033[0m"
echo -e "\033[4;34mblue underlined\033[0m"
```

I'm not sure about support on OSX though... you may need to try a different [escape character](https://superuser.com/questions/33914/why-doesnt-echo-support-e-escape-when-using-the-e-argument-in-macosx) - colors in the terminal may also need to [be enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550288/mac-os-x-terminal-colors).

Comment: `echo -e "\033[31mred\033[0m"` Did work on my OS X.

Comment: Also, the first line with ´-C 999´ works good, but I still want to see the entire log even if there is no match, it only shows the entire log if there is a match.

EDIT: The way I solved that was to include a word that is always there.

Answer (score 2):

Do use grep. Have `^` be one of your search terms so that you still get every line (but it will be uncolored, unless it contains visible matches).

**Example:**

```
grep -e '[[:upper:]][[:alnum:]]*' -e ^ <<EOF
This Is An
example file.
All lines 
in it will be printed, and all
words that start 
with a Capital
letter will be Colorized.
EOF
```

(This uses a heredoc (search the shell manual for "Here Documents"). Piped stdin or a real file would have been just as fine).

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: Done __________

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to arbitrarily change text colors, you can use ANSI escape sequences to do that. For example, **ESC[31m** will change the text color to red, **ESC[37m** will produce white, etc.

You could use sed to insert the escape codes for certain colors in specific places in the stream. [Here's an example of someone doing this very thing.](http://www.bramschoenmakers.nl/en/node/511.html)

In addition to changing colors, you can do lots of other screen output manipulations. [Here's a reference.](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php)